# How can I fix this problem related to Conv2D of Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have created the following neural networks:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(3, (3,3), activation="relu", padding="same", input_shape=constants.GRID_SHAPE))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(constants.NUM_ACTIONS), activation="softmax")
```

where `constants.GRID_SHAPE` is (4,12).

I get the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 4, 12)

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a 3D input shape excluding the batch size if you plan to use the `Conv2D` layer. Currently you have a 2D input shape. Also make sure the activation function `softmax` is part of the `Dense` layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (3,3), activation="relu", padding="same", input_shape=(4, 12, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax"))
```

If your input data is of the shape `(samples, 4, 12)`, you can use `data = tf.expand_dims(data, axis=-1)` to add an extra dimension to your data to make it compatible with the `Conv2D` layer.

If you do not want to add a new dimension, you could also simply use a `Conv1D` layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(3, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", input_shape=(4, 12)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax"))
```

Comment: Now the network is correctly created but when I use `model.predict` I have the following error: >ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 4, 12, 1), found shape=(None, 12, 1)

Comment: Yeah, your test data also needs to have the correct input shape when calling model.predict.. you are missing the 4 part ;)

Comment: The shape of my data is (4,12,1), I do not understand what is wrong

Comment: You are now missing the batch dimension. Try `test_data = tf.expand_dims(test_data, axis=0)`